# Python: How to replace a property with a regular attribute?

Tags: python, properties

The base class has this:

```
def _management_form(self):
    # code here
    return form
management_form = property(_management_form)
```

In my derived class, I'm trying to write this:

```
self.management_form = self.myfunc()
```

But of course it doesn't work. It tells me "can't set attribute" because that property has no setter. But I don't want to set it, I want to redefine what "managent_form" means. I tried putting `del self.managent_form` first, but that didn't work either. So how do I unproperty-ize it?

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? It sounds like breaking the is-a relationship...

Comment: Well the way the property is defined, it reconstructs the object every time you use it, which is just stupid. I put a print statement in there, and it gets called like 10 times, and it's causing problems because I need to modify some of its properties, but its futile if its going to get replaced next time its used. I have no idea why they (Django developers) did it like this. Basically, I just want it to be constructed once, and then return that instance from then on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could assign to the class, instead of the instance:

```
MyClass.management_form = property(self.myfunc)
```

Of course, this changes the class itself for all instances (even preexisting ones). If this is OK, you can also call it exactly once, rather than in every derived-class constructor (which I'm guessing is what you're doing now).

Otherwise, you can override it in the derived class in the usual manner:

```
class MyOtherClass(MyClass):
    def _new_mf(self):
        # Better code
        return form
    management_form = property(new_mf)
```

Comment: I guess overriding it to just return the property is good enough... kind of odd that you can de-property it though. Everything else in Python is completely mutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `CachedAttribute` implemented via a descriptor as shown here: [Replace property for perfomance gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388258/replace-property-for-perfomance-gain?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(Unlike a standard `property` such a descriptor can be overridden directly by an instance attribute - in new style classes & PY3 too.)